# I can't read the Uri when passing it using setOnClickListener

Tags: android, android-activity, uri

In MainActivity I start ThirdActivity:

```
public void startThirdActivity(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 2);// Activity is started with requestCode 2
    }
```

In ThirdActivity I am passing my imageUris and Text to MainActivity using Bundle:

```
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        returnIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        args.putSerializable("ARRAYLIST",(Serializable)imageUris);
        args.putSerializable("TEXT",(Serializable)Text);
        returnIntent.putExtra("imageUris", args);
        setResult(2,returnIntent);
        finish();
    }
```

And then in MainActivity using onActivityResult I call startSecondActivity:

```
            myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startSecondActivity(MainActivity.this, imageUris);
                }
            });
```

startSecondActivity:

```
        Intent i = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        args.putSerializable("ARRAYLIST",(Serializable)imageUris);
        i.putExtra("BUNDLE",args);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
```

If I uncomment `// startSecondActivity(MainActivity.this, imageUris);`, then everythin works fine, I get my images in SecondActivity:
[Good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWCzM.png)
but if I call it inside of OnClick, then I can't read Uri:
[Error reading Uri](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uI4BV.png)
I tried to pass context and to set flag, but nothing changes.
LogCat:
resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri:
Unable to open content

Comment: How's this class? 
        args.putSerializable("ARRAYLIST",(Serializable)imageUris);
It's a List<String>?

Comment: No, it's ArrayList<Uri>

Comment: Try to change to use `Parcelable` instead 
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("ARRAYLIST", uriList);
and 
ArrayList<Uri> uriList = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("ARRAYLIST");